# Add suffix to Object keys with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, redux

In the context of Redux async actions, I need to pass in an object and retrieve each key with a some suffixes. Heres is an example:

```
const actions = createAsyncActions('MY_ACTIONS')
```

The function should use the input string as the main object key and the add suffixes to it, so the resulting type of actions is:

```
{
    MY_ACTIONS: string
    MY_ACTIONS_PENDING: string
    MY_ACTIONS_FULFILLED: string
    MY_ACTIONS_REJECTED: string
}
```

Comment: you want to pass object key and get object with suffix keys ?

Comment: The diffuculty here is constructing the return type. You can create a wide return type of `{ [key: string]: string }`, but I can't work out a way to create the narrow type with specific keys. I tried some funky stuff with mapped types but can't land it yet.

Comment: I believe this issue is covered [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754)