# Define prefix for object keys using types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

I have the following interface that defines an object where properties can be of two different types.

```js
export interface OptionsA {
    name: string;
}

export interface OptionsB {
    parts: number;
}

export interface OptionsConfig {
    [key: string]: OptionsA | OptionsB;
}
```

This works fine, but there is a restriction that properties of type `OptionsB` must be prefixed with `"@"`.

For example;

```js
const example: OptionsConfig = {
    '@sample': {parts: 1},
    other: {name: 'example'}
};
```

So the above works fine, but the following example would be incorrect.

```js
const example: OptionsConfig = {
    '@sample': {parts: 1},
    other: {name: 'example'},
    '@wrong': {name: 'error'}
};
```

I am wondering if it is possible with TypeScript to declare that `@wrong`can only implement the `OptionsB` interface, because it has the `@` prefix.

Alternatively, is there another approach to achieve a similar kind of restriction.

Comment: Nope, no string literal types manipulations of any kind are possibe

Comment: See also [Add suffix to Object keys with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53317721/add-suffix-to-object-keys-with-typescript) question and [Augment Key during Type Mapping](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) github issue

Answer (score 34):

Typescript 4.1 gave us [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types), so you can do something like this:

```js
type addPrefixToObject<T, P extends string> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends string ? `${P}${K}` : never]: T[K]
}
```

Then, your `OptionsConfig` becomes

```js
export interface OptionsConfig {
    [key: string]: OptionsA | addPrefixToObject<OptionsB, '@'>;
}
```

Example available in [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgJnACgJwgMwJYA8AqB7AeQCMArCAY2AB4cAaKRKCLYCAOzgGcpPhkM2AcwB8UALxQA3gFgAUFCgBtANJQBUANYQQeNFByxuq5qw7de-IVAD8UAAYASSYgC+T5S7tQAXFDYQANwhkAF1fHBUQuRc5OQB6OP1waABVYAwAG25AMGpAeD-Y2QFWZDQYcmgCMHS8Nk4AQSk5BQU2GABbCF8LAUEAbmiCouDS8qhK6tqAIUb5ZrAYZGBOXzYAVzaiYP7ZGNk5IZKyiqqMGs4AYRrMQRnmpS0QLr4esLGTs4aAH1gEFHRsfDEMiUKjjU5TegAcgAApDhNtdnJyGdgFA2iBLmxrr4wWdMddxFIXNt4okAOp4ZAaZZydH4jCCAB0MGAfAAjITJK0Or5IdyIJDibSMVcGczWcgAEycgBE0Pmi04Mt8bKFsjpoqZLL4AGZZfKFktlVA2fR+bz+YKSbIElAAKLIZCU8LJKCQyRQBVLFbrTbIXpQFyQtTcNh4VEwTicBmtIgZaDAPBQUCQN242pfH5IVCYXCEUgUajpziTehymXCSGM4X0rUSgAssq9SpVarkQA).

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding `K in keyof T as K ...` how am I supposed to read this? It's exactly what I'm looking for but it's the first time I see that syntax in particular and I'm frustrated that it works but I don't understand :)

Comment: `K in keyof T` iterates over every key in `T` and assigns it to type `K`. The `as` clause allows you to map each of the `K` keys. You'd expect `[K in keyof T as ${P}${K}]: T[K]` to work, but that complains saying `K` can be a symbol and you can't concatenate a symbol with a string. So we first check if it's a string, and then map it.

Comment: Very clear explanation, thanks @azizj

Comment: this doesn't work when keys are numbers

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR: Copy the first code block**

While this maybe wasn't possible at the time this question was asked, I came across this while I was searching for a solution that I could simply copy & paste. [TypeScript 4.1 gave us template literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) which make this implementation possible.

Full example on TypeScript playground is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgJnACgJwgMwJYA8A8AVAaQhABoo8V1soItgIA7OAZymeGQwYHMA+KALzkiIGnUYs2HLtygB+KAAMAJAG8KqTFgC+awsW2KoALigMIANwjIA3AFgAUKEhRUAWwD2Vylvw-sEHAiZBpUWGL0TKzsnDz8QqFagSIREqzwSJrYOFxo1sLEIf5Y-Ar6oqYA5JX2TuDQYFlYgQBqMAA2AK4Q+ADyAEYAVhAAxsCpUVAeQ6PARU3JxBOSMTLzYcvR0nGC5APDY5tQqgDaBFBcrhCe3k1+C0GF5MW8ALqmufl4bV0Q2vLkH7dExmSzWWqOZzQDLFPAefazPozQ60SKSaYHObPJpHVY7ISqRxQKBnC4MWAIYo4ADWxA8aD2yKxiWwb1MjTCrQ63SRmLIBHWWl4jm0jjFDgA9BLyPUoABVYAYdqsQBg1IB4P-FtDAHmQ4y49GQaBgI2gvTAio8DGYAEFjkTiWYYG4IKY8dxaqKHI4tTq9QwDUaTVAzRarQAhO0OB1QMAwXXMUwMTpufrgkWarDa3VkgPG03mjCW5gAYUtmFkhKjDpOtJAru23HewYLRdtAB8KZkwnCEWMcCHC+GyJUAAKVXge8UjIvjNwgUsMcumAdFhfl3aqbQQyXSgDqOupCccc7XGG4ADoYMAOABGDcMJ0uqCVB-Oypb4-zstny-X5AAJg3AAiEdY3jIDTBvD8HBPb8LyvDgAGZgNAuNgGYCCoBvMhXyfF9H3fbcpSgABRZBkB1Uw8FlSpVBjNCEzMZNU1sKBtEqC5WAYDxxhgZhmDPB9+naaBgA8KAoWfFcrXbTtYXhJl+xbIcoBAoDeEqc9P1PeC-wAFmAsD0MwqDtyAA).

---

First, we need to define some utility types to automatically prefix object types. This can be done with the following code block. If you're not yet familiar with them, I suggest you first read up on [template literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) and [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) types which are both used heavily in the code below

```js
type addPrefix<TKey, TPrefix extends string> = TKey extends string
  ? `${TPrefix}${TKey}`
  : never;

type removePrefix<TPrefixedKey, TPrefix extends string> = TPrefixedKey extends addPrefix<infer TKey, TPrefix>
  ? TKey
  : '';

type prefixedValue<TObject extends object, TPrefixedKey extends string, TPrefix extends string> = TObject extends {[K in removePrefix<TPrefixedKey, TPrefix>]: infer TValue}
  ? TValue
  : never;

type addPrefixToObject<TObject extends object, TPrefix extends string> = {
  [K in addPrefix<keyof TObject, TPrefix>]: prefixedValue<TObject, K, TPrefix>
}
```

- `addPrefix` takes in an existing `TKey` and adds a `TPrefix` to it, if `TKey` extends the type string. If it does not extend the type `string`, `never` is returned instead as a type.
- `removePrefix` takes in a `TPrefixedKey` and a `TPrefix` and removes `TPrefix` from the key by using `infer` to retrieve the original key that was used to create the `TPrefixedKey`.
- `prefixedValue` takes in a `TObject` which is **not** prefixed. Then it infers `TValue` from the `TPrefixedKey` after the prefix was removed with `removePrefix`. If this succeeds `TValue` is returned. Otherwise, an empty string is returned, which is still a valid object signature.
- `addPrefixToObject` puts all of the above together. It maps over all of the keys which are currently inside `TObject` and prefixes them. The value is retrieved by using `prefixedValue`.

---

If you put this into action it seems to work out quite fine:

```js
const myConfig: OptionsConfig = {};

// Works:
myConfig.attr1 = {name: 'name'};
myConfig.attr2 = {"@parts": 1};
myConfig.attr3 = {"@parts": 1, name: 'name'};

// Error: Type '{ parts: number; }' is not assignable to type 'OptionsA | addPrefixToObject<OptionsB, "@">'.
myConfig.attr4 = {"parts": 1};

// Prints as:
// type prefixedOptionB = {
//    "@parts": number;
// }
type PrefixedOptionB = addPrefixToObject<OptionsB, '@'>;
```

And autocompletion is also working accordingly:
[image: screenshot of autocompletion]

---

All of this can probably be optimized further, so if you have any suggestions please leave a comment.

Full example on TypeScript playground is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgJnACgJwgMwJYA8A8AVAaQhABoo8V1soItgIA7OAZymeGQwYHMA+KALzkiIGnUYs2HLtygB+KAAMAJAG8KqTFgC+awsW2KoALigMIANwjIA3AFgAUKEhRUAWwD2Vylvw-sEHAiZBpUWGL0TKzsnDz8QqFagSIREqzwSJrYOFxo1sLEIf5Y-Ar6oqYA5JX2TuDQYFlYgQBqMAA2AK4Q+ADyAEYAVhAAxsCpUVAeQ6PARU3JxBOSMTLzYcvR0nGC5APDY5tQqgDaBFBcrhCe3k1+C0GF5MW8ALqmufl4bV0Q2vLkH7dExmSzWWqOZzQDLFPAefazPozQ60SKSaYHObPJpHVY7ISqRxQKBnC4MWAIYo4ADWxA8aD2yKxiWwb1MjTCrQ63SRmLIBHWWl4jm0jjFDgA9BLyPUoABVYAYdqsQBg1IB4P-FtDAHmQ4y49GQaBgI2gvTAio8DGYAEFjkTiWYYG4IKY8dxaqKHI4tTq9QwDUaTVAzRarQAhO0OB1QMAwXXMUwMTpufrgkWarDa3VkgPG03mjCW5gAYUtmFkhKjDpOtJAru23HewYLRdtAB8KZkwnCEWMcCHC+GyJUAAKVXge8UjIvjNwgUsMcumAdFhfl3aqbQQyXSgDqOupCccc7XGG4ADoYMAOABGDcMJ0uqCVB-Oypb4-zstny-X5AAJg3AAiEdY3jIDTBvD8HBPb8LyvDgAGZgNAuNgGYCCoBvMhXyfF9H3fbcpSgABRZBkB1Uw8FlSpVBjNCEzMZNU1sKBtEqC5WAYDxxhgZhmDPB9+naaBgA8KAoWfFcrXbTtYXhJl+xbIcoBAoDeEqc9P1PeC-wAFmAsD0MwqDtyAA).

Comment: Wow! Interesting. And I don't like to spoil the fun, but the OP wanted the propertynames of OptionsConfig prefixed for values implementing OptionB. Unprefixed names should implement OptionA. So ´attr2´ and ´attr3´ in your code should give error, because Argument of type '{"@parts": number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ name: string; }'. And ´myConfig["@sample"] = {parts: 42}´ should not give error.

Comment: @Superole yeah you're right – seems like I got OP wrong. I'll check whether I can adjust this. If not I'll just add a disclaimer at the top. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

One quick answer for enforcing prefix using types (Starting in TS4.1)-

```
type strWithPre = `pre-${string}`
```

Comment: With the more recent versions of TS this should be the accepted answer - or the accepted one should be updated to include this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the other answers I have an object `colors` for [Stitches](https://stitches.dev/) but for each color used as a prop in a component I do the following.

```js
const colors = {
  white: '#ffffff',
  black: '#000000',
  transparent: 'transparent',
  text: '$black',
  background: '$white',
  indigo: '#0757D6',
  purple: '#7928ca',
  success: '#17c964',
  warning: '#f5a623',
  yellow2: '#F2C94C',
  error: '#f21361',
  primary: '#518AE3',
  secondary: '$purple',
  icon: '#BBBBBB',
  primaryOpacity: '#DEEBFF',
  secondaryOpacity: '#DBC8F0',
  errorOpacity: '#FFC3D8',
  subText: '#707070',
  gray1: '#333333',
  bgCard: '#F9F9FA',
  bgText: 'rgba(234, 234, 234, 0.7)',
};
```

To get `ColorType` automatic try this:

```js
type addPrefixToObject<TObject extends object, TPrefix extends string> = `${TPrefix}${keyof TObject}`

export type ColorType = addPrefixToObject<typeof colors, '$'>;
```

This returns a type that will be `"$black" | "$white" | "$text"` (and so on). I.e. it returns each color key with the prefix `$`.