# Which is the best way to define the type of dynamic data-attributes in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typeerror, custom-data-attribute

I need a React prop to deal with all possible html attributes of an HTML div element part of a React component, but I'm having an issue with Typescript strictness vs React possibilities.

Here the component:

```
import React from 'react'

type DivAttrs = {
  container?: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
}

...

<div {...divAttributes?.container}>
```

And here the prop const provided to the component:

```
const divAttributes: DivAttrs = {
  container: {
    'aria-describedby': 'test',
    'data-custom-attribute': 'test',
    'data-random-attribute': 'test',
    id: 'test'    
  }
}
```

The props `data-custom-attribute` and `data-random-attribute` give these errors

```
(property) 'data-custom-attribute': string
Type '{ 'aria-describedby': string; 'data-custom-attribute': string; 'data-random-attribute': string; id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''data-custom-attribute'' does not exist in type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.(2322)
```

What would be the perfect solution to fix this issue? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update for TypeScript 4.1+:**

The introduction of [Template Literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) allows us to create a type that accepts both `HTMLAttributes` and custom `data-*` attributes:

```
type DivAttrs = {
  container?: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & {[dataAttibute: `data-${string}`]: string}
}
```

**Previous solution**

The `data-custom-attribute` and `data-random-attribute` properties do not exist in the `React.HTMLAttributes` type or any pre-existing type, hence your best bet would be to combine the existing `React.HTMLAttributes` type (to still get access to common `HTMLDivElement` element attributes) with your own `CustomAttrs`:

```
interface CustomAttrs {
  'data-custom-attribute': string;
  'data-random-attribute': string;
}

type DivAttrs = {
  container?: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & CustomAttrs,
}
```

Comment: So is it impossible to have dynamic approach? I se your solution works, but it is not really my intention to cover all possible client requests of data attributes. It is clear `React.HTMLAttributes` is not offering support to data attributes. But does it feel frustrating that dynamic types for data attributes can't be typed legally in Typescript with proper types, since they are part of the `HTMLElement.dataset` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset ? Anyway, thanks

Comment: I see what you mean. Because the postfix for ```data-*``` is completely defined by the developer, TypeScript will not be able to validate it out of the box. Additionally, because TypeScript has no regex capabilities, it cannot make sure that the attribute property key names start with ```data-```, so unfortunately the only solution is for you to explicitly define a custom type like in the example above.

Comment: The above comment is no longer valid as TypeScript 4.1 has introduced a new feature called `Template Literals` which facilitates the definition of custom string structures.

Answer (score 1):

we can add an index signature into the prop’s type.

```html
type DivAttrs = {
  container?: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & { [x: string]: any},
}
```

Comment: This worked very well on my side and with this new feature of typescript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70387184 you can specify that the properties must have the "data-" prefix