# Typescript template literal as generic parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an API that returns an object in the form similar to this:

```
{
  foo: number,
  foo_comment: string,
  foo_formatted_value: string,
  _foo_created_by: string
  bar: number,
  bar_comment: string,
  bar_formatted_value: string,
  _bar_created_by: string
}
```

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57510388/define-prefix-for-object-keys-using-types-in-typescript), it looks like I can make a generic that will add a prefix to the keys of an object. **Is there a way to have a generic that accepts a template literal parameter in like manner?**

I am thinking something like this:

```
type Data = {
  foo: number,
  bar: number
}

type Template<T, TemplateFunction extends TemplateLiteralFunction,  V = void> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends string ? TemplateFunction(K) : never]: (V extends void? T[K]: V)
}

type DataAndMetaData = 
      Data &
      Template<Data,`${1}_comment`>&
      Template<Data,`${1}_formatted_value`>&
      Template<Data,`_${1}_created_by`>;
```

Of course, the `${1}` is the part that doesn't work. Perhaps if there were type-generating functions: `(Key:string)=>'${Key}...'`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd want intersections and not unions, like `Data & Template<Data, ...`, if you expect the resulting type to have all those properties.  Would you [edit] to fix that?

Comment: You can't use template literals this way, but if you're just doing simple substitutions you don't need to.  Does something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nngy6m) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That is exactly what I am going for, thank you!

Comment: Could you also fix `number` vs `string`?  Your `T[K]` implies you want `number` everywhere but I'm seeing `string` in your example on top

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The values can be different types. The T[K] is just referencing the result of the original object T which could be anything.

Comment: Your example at the top has `foo` of type `number` but `foo_comment` as type `string`.  The `Template` type you proposed would never turn `number` into `string` this way, and neither does mine. You get a type with all `number` in it. So either the `string` in your example at the top is not relevant and should be changed to `number` to remove distractions, or it *is* relevant, in which case you are asking for the substituted property keys to possibly have different value types from the original, in which case `T[K]` would never accomplish that.  I'm imagining it's the former, but only you know.

Comment: To put it another way: presumably you're really asking about string substitution here, and the exact behavior with value types is something you could handle separately and isn't the crux of the question.  If so, then we should probably just have the examples have all `string` or all `number` value type, and you can do whatever you want with your actual code.

Comment: I understand, I have updated it. Thanks!

Comment: Blegh, you've updated it the more complicated way.  Fine, I'll amend my answer to match it

Comment: Where is `string` in your bottom example?  Shouldn't you be writing `Data & Template<Data,\`${1}_comment\`,string>&...`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't abstract over [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) in this way, but you don't need to.  Instead you can take plain string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) and *use* template literal type inference to substitute your `"${1}"` string with the keys you want.

It could look like this:

```
type Template<T, S extends string, V = void, I extends string = "${1}"> = {
    [K in keyof T as K extends string ?
    S extends `${infer F}${I}${infer R}` ? `${F}${K}${R}` : K :
    K]: V extends void ? T[K] : V;
}
```

And we can use it like this:

```
type DataAndMetaData =
    Data &
    Template<Data, "${1}_comment" | "${1}_formatted_value" | "_${1}_created_by", string>

/* type DataAndMetaData = Data & {
    foo_comment: string;
    foo_formatted_value: string;
    _foo_created_by: string;
    bar_comment: string;
    bar_formatted_value: string;
    _bar_created_by: string;
}*/
```

Note that you *could* write `Data & Template<Data, "${1}_comment", string> & Template<Data,  "${1}_formatted_value", string> & Template<Data, "_${1}_created_by", string>`, but it's cleaner to use the [distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) behavior to get the desired output type all at once (or nearly so... still need that initial `Data &` in there).

Also, in the above, the `"${1}"` value is essentially arbitrary, since we're not really using template literal interpolation.  Maybe you want to use a different symbol to represent the thing to be replaced. I added another type parameter, `I`, to represent this value, and made it [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `"${1}"`.  So you might want to change the default, or even set it explicitly when you use `Template`:

```
type Also = Template<Data, "*" | "*_xyz", string, "*">
/* type Also = {
    foo: string;
    foo_xyz: string;
    bar: string;
    bar_xyz: string;
} */
```

Also note that the definition above only does a single substitution and will behave strangely if you include multiple instances of the sigil:

```
type Hmm = Template<Data, "${1}_or_not_${1}_that_is_the_question">;
/* type Hmm = {
    "foo_or_not_${1}_that_is_the_question": number;
    "bar_or_not_${1}_that_is_the_question": number;
} */
```

I'm assuming that doesn't matter, but if it does, one could write a recursive version of the substitution logic to deal with it—in another question, since it's out of scope for this one.

Comment: wow, what a explanation. great.. boss...great . awesome.