# A mapped type does not seem to work as expected in a generic function

Tags: typescript

I wanted to create a generic type that would represent a record of string values, with one Prefix argument that would define the prefix of each property in the record.

This type works when used normally, but it does not work inside a generic. I found a solution by using a Record instead of key mappings, though I'd like to understand why the first solution does not work. Record works for my current use case, but the mapped type is much more flexible as [it allows to assign a different type per individual key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57510388/define-prefix-for-object-keys-using-types-in-typescript).

```
type MyPrefixedTypeKeys = 
    'foo' |
    'bar';

type MyPrefixedType<P extends string> = {
    [K in MyPrefixedTypeKeys as `${P}${K}`]: string
}

type test = MyPrefixedType<'pre_'>; // { pre_foo: string, pre_bar: string }

// It does not work in generics
function createPrefixedType<P extends string>(prefix: P): MyPrefixedType<P> {
    let o: MyPrefixedType<P> = {
        [`${prefix}foo`]: '',
        // Note that it does not require the bar property
    }

    type x = MyPrefixedType<P>; // { }

    o[`${prefix}bar`] = ''; // Error

    return o;
}

// I found a solution by using a Record type, though I still wonde why the above
// does not work.

type MyPrefixedType2<P extends string> = Record<`${P}${MyPrefixedTypeKeys}`, string>

function createPrefixedType2<P extends string>(prefix: P): MyPrefixedType2<P> {
    let o: MyPrefixedType2<P> = {
        [`${prefix}foo`]: '',
        [`${prefix}bar`]: '',
    } as MyPrefixedType2<P>;

    o[`${prefix}bar`] = '';

    return o;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAKAnCAzAlgDwgEwCrggGkIQBnKAXigCgo6oByFAe2YagB9b6GAjAQ0QMA3NWqhIsBMnRY8BADzwoEDMAgA7bOVLBEaDQHMAfJSgBvbnQDahKAalJUmHPkjEyUfuQAGAEnN4AF8AwiCfAF0ALihdfSNqILEJaHVdMzgnWVdFBjBkAH0GY2EoAHoyiyh8iAKWZhi4g0MAGmrCgURGvWaoJOoKqABJYChsZghyDWZRgHdmRABrew0oQ00IfQBjUmoUAFcNLeA0ZlWt5H51LJd5SCUVNU1tWJ6jYwAKGtkY+ABKGKZGS3NwQJSmSz0KAAGwgowajmBclB4LMkKh9Gs-nM30wQXqkRiDAYLSsGMGADkZqkABZXeyjcaTKDTUbIACO+zQyCgwBp0E67WYkEQoDJ-ShKSgGAy0mcyMU8BK5Uq5j6YihzCxAVxGCCnUiZmJpUGAFFEIgFhr6MhgPtEKtmKJ+oMhlAWIdsF5YsxofsTmcoLwQFB9qRevwoAAlCBbBZelJtPnMfaGGnDV5oaHQqDzLTQWY0kN86D8XjMABuEAGlSZUxmuYWiwAdMkCIj5TlIAAmB6qdRaHRvExmGNxxDYBTY4IBIGdu5EEikcJtJrvMQHI4B86Xa5IrsQXvKfvPIfxExfJG-AEd7ILo8Qsmw+GAuV30EPtFkqHanFI-GsISjAkt+mLYrq+qCEBxKklCQReOQc7vgQD6iGSWrgf+BoREaIjWnQtr2o6zrUEAA)

Comment: I just don't think TypeScript has the capability of constructing a template literal type to represent those computed keys.

Comment: Looks like multiple issues in a single question post and you're asking multiple questions. One is the issue with generic template literal remapping (which seems to be the *main* question, similar to [ms/TS#50030](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50030) maybe).  One is the issue where template literal *values* are not automatically given template literal *types* (so you might need `[\`${prefix}foo\` as const]` instead of just `[\`${prefix}foo\`]`)

Comment: One is the issue where computed keys are widened to string (so `{[k]: v}` is often of type `Record<string, typeof v>` and not `Record<typeof k, typeof v>`).  Could you [edit] the question so that you're clearly asking a [single question about about a single issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741/511366)? If you want to ask about others you always can post new questions. If you do this and want me to take another look, pls mention @jcalz in a comment.

Comment: Great question. [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAKAnCAzAlgDwgEwCrggGkIQBnKAXigCgo6oByFAe2YagB9b6GAjAQ0QMA3NWqhIsBMnRY8BADzwoEDMAgA7bOVLBEaDQHMAfJSgBvbnQDahKAalJUmHPkjEyUfuQAGAEnN4AF8AwiCfAF0ALihdfSNqILEUAFcNAGNgNGYNKHTkfnUnWVdFZVV1LR09AxMACjAZTBj4AEoYuGKXeUglU0s6ZGAUxFzzIOEoAHopqAA5ZhVERGZEAEJEsXSc3SgMM3yIQoguuTcIOoAiAA0ATQAtS9bRam2NUmYAGwgAOk-mQx1DA-O73ASIH7AZgAVTAkEQAGFvBdWs9prMJDgvNV4oY1kA) of the relevant part that should really cause a compile error but doesn't. (Whichever error that would be is another question, but there should be one.)

Comment: I created an issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51290